# Function returns only one output at time

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with this function (I have very little experience with Matlab). The function is supposed to return 3 different arguments but always returns only one. I mean, to get Y out I have to remove Tot and Z from the output arguments! As it is now only Tot is returned.

```
function [Tot, Z, Y] = something( A )

%A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];

Z=cumsum(A);             %cumulative sum of columns
Y=cumsum(A,2);              %cumulative sum of rows
Tot = sum(Z(:))+sum(Y(:));    %Total sum of Z+Y

end
```

Why is doing that ? What am I doing wrong, I need all 3 arguments out.

Comment: How are you calling the function?  The proper call to receive all three arguments would be:  `[A, B, C] = something (X)`, where Tot would be placed into A, Z int B, and Y into C.  If you just want Y, you can use the tilde operator to ignore other outputs:  `[~,~,C] = something(X)`'.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks a lot for your advice. Please post it as answer I will be happy to accept it. As I said, I am a noob in Matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper call to receive all three arguments would be: `[A, B, C] = something (X)`, where `Tot` would be placed into `A`, `Z` into `B`, and `Y` into `C`. If you just want `Y`, you can use the "tilde" operator to ignore other outputs: `[~,~,C] = something(X)`.